# Retrieve values from json encoded string

Tags: javascript, json

I am storing a concatenated string like this:

```
echo json_encode($PostedDate.$Places.$Company.$Designation.$ProjectDetails.$DesiredCandidate.$HRName.$HRContact.$Email);
```

I can split this string using JavaScript and store values in an array. But what I want to know is that suppose any of the values above is null, will it affect the array position?

Because, I want to keep the array location fixed. For example:

myArray[0] must hold $PostedDate.

If $PostedDate is null, then also, myArray[0] must be equal to NULL. $Places must not take the position of myArray[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the strings onto a php array like so:

echo json_encode(array($PostedDate,$Places,$Company));

Answer (score 1):

[You may find this interesting on how to preserve array location](http://dev-tips.com/featured/remove-an-item-from-an-array-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

Put it into an array in php and then json_encode the array. Then you dont need to do your crazy split on the javascript side and you dont need to worry about preserving a position in a string.